# Determining approximate prediction interval using moments

Tags: moments, prediction-interval

Given the values of mean, and the next 3 central moments of a continuous random variable X > 0 with unknown pdf, is it possible to derive an approximate interval $(a,b)$ within which X will fall with probability $(1-\alpha)$ ?

$$
P(a < X < b) = 1-\alpha
$$

Comment: The first central moment is going to be 0, so that's not much use at pinning down an interval. Presumably you mean the first raw moment, and the next 3 central moments after that. Moments really don't pin down distributions very well, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did mean first raw moment (i.e. mean) :)

Comment: Not quite the thing you're after, but you may find [Bhattacharyya's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Bhattacharyya.27s_inequality) of some interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [Edgeworth series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series) which led me to [Cornish–Fisher expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornish%E2%80%93Fisher_expansion).

Comment: Also a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807398/how-to-generate-distributions-given-mean-sd-skew-and-kurtosis-in-r